# What happens when removing NaN values from a column?

Tags: python, nan

In Pandas, After dropping NaN values from a column, what's the value stored at the index where the NaN value was removed? I was able to successfully drop NaN values from a column but the shape of the df is intact, yet the size of that particular column changed.

```
1445    70.0
**1446     NaN**
1447    80.0
1448    70.0
1449    21.0
1450    60.0
1451    78.0
1452    35.0
1453    90.0
1454    62.0
1455    62.0
1456    85.0
1457    66.0
1458    68.0
1459    75.0
Name: LotFrontage, dtype: float64
Size of LotFrontage before removing NaN values: 1460
```

This is what I get after removing the NaN values

```
1444    63.0
1445    70.0
1447    80.0
1448    70.0
1449    21.0
1450    60.0
1451    78.0
1452    35.0
1453    90.0
1454    62.0
1455    62.0
1456    85.0
1457    66.0
1458    68.0
1459    75.0
Name: LotFrontage, dtype: float64
New size of LotFrontage after removing NaN values: 1201
```

I get the following error when trying to allocate the value of index 1446:

[enter image description here][1]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-7cb9d14fb3e0> in <module>()
      3 print("New size of LotFrontage after revoving NaN values: " + str(iowa['LotFrontage'].size))
      4 print(iowa['LotFrontage'][1445])
----> 5 print(iowa['LotFrontage'][1446])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:
   4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1446
```

Comment: I think you mean "In Pandas" rather than "In Python" right?  If so, please edit your question and tags accordingly.

Comment: Yes. I mean Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you must have used "dropna" function to drop NaN values. You can drop various ways using 'dropna' function. By default it drop row wise and drop row if any column in that row got 'NaN' value in it. You can alter this behavior by setting various parameters as can be referred [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

And when row will be dropped, shape will surely change. In your case shape must not have changed because you have "not dropped inplace". Without setting 'inplace' to 'True', "dropna" function will return you dropped dataframe rather than changing it in the original dataframe.

If dropping the index is the desirable behavior, then use dropna either of ways:

```
df_final = df.dropna()
or
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

If you have multiple columns in your dataframe and only want to drop row when all columns have NaN, then use:

```
df_final = df.dropna(how='all')
or
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

If you have only single column and want to secure the index, then you can try replacing the NaN values with the suitable value like:

```
df_final = df.fillna(0)
or
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

For more on 'fillna', you can refer this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first column, it just an index. You should reset the index after dropping some values.
(If you want to see or add the old index to your dataframe, set drop=False. Otherwise, it will drop the old index)

```
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Your dataframe after dropping some values contains only 1201 rows, so there is no row at 1446 anymore. That is why you get the KeyError: 1446